# How to Change Task subject name for mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);

Tags: singleemailmessage, activityhistory

I am sending a mail through batch class and i am setting `mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);` also. So the mail saving as an Activity history.

[image]

Mail:

[image]

As I am setting `mail.setSaveAsActivity(true)` Mail name and Task subject are saving as same names. I need to change the Subject of the task. Is there any way to change the Task name when we set `mail.setSaveAsActivity(true)` in mail?

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
               // mail.setCcAddresses(currentPractEmail);  
                mail.setTargetObjectId(w.Contact__c);
                mail.setWhatid(w.id);
                mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owe.id);

                    mail.SetTemplateid(et);

                mailList.add(mail);
          //      eleInnerList.clear();
            //    system.debug('***BODY***'+mail.);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose we cannot modify the task subject while creating the email message.

A workaround that I can suggest is, setting save as activity as `false`, like `mail.setSaveAsActivity(false)` and create a task record manually using apex code.

Another way, i would suggest is to write a before trigger on Task object and change the subject by identifying the subject string(i.e a identifying string which classifies the task that, whether it was created from email).

Similar kind of example is being discussed [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000i9eRAAQ). See if this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Hemant! I have tried with Apex code but having a problem with converting HTML Template to Plain Text so I will try to write trigger